# GIZA++ - How is alignment score calculated?

Tags: moses, giza++, smt-language-processing

This might be more of a math problem,
but I couldn't find any relevant document elsewhere.

I just want to figure out which equation is used to calculate alignment score in GIZA++.

Might anyone have an idea?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it helps, I found [this document](http://code.google.com/p/giza-pp/issues/attachmentText?id=8&aid=697742396599277757&name=README-rst&token=40fba3d449abc12366b98b04cfe7dbc1), which includes the following description:

> Implements full IBM-4 alignment model with a dependency of word
>   classes as described in (Brown et al. 1993)

Following up that reference leads to a paper entitled *"The Mathematics of Statistical Machine Translation: Parameter Estimation"*, which you can find [in PDF format here](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~sfchang/course/svia-F03/papers/brown-machine-translate-93.pdf).

The paper gives details of the math underlying the 5 alignment models and is too verbose to paste here. Perhaps you can see if this is sufficiently detailed in its description of Model 4, which is what I assume is used by GIZA++.

There is also [this PDF](https://www.prhlt.upv.es/~evidal/students/doct/sht/transp/OLD/giza4p.pdf), which summarises the models and training process.

Comment: the second two links are broken

Comment: @chokamp Thanks - I've updated the two broken links.

Answer (score 0):

In short, word alignments and translation probabilities are learned in multiple iterations of Expectation Maximum algorithm.

The "Statistical Machine Translation" of Philip Koehn has a chapter for word alignments. Check [statmt.org](http://statmt.org/) for more information.